# Merge DataFrame with many-to-many

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames containing examples, I would like to see if a example of DataFrame 1 is present in DataFrame 2.

Normally I would aggregate the rows per example and simply merge the DataFrames. Unfortunately the merging has to be done with a "matching table" which has a many-to-many relationship between the keys (id_low vs. id_high).

**Simplified example**

*Matching Table:*

[image]

*Input DataFrames*

[image]

*They are therefore matchable like this:*

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

**Simplified example (for Python)**

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe 1 - containing 1 Example
d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Example': {0: 'Example 1', 1: 'Example 1', 2: 'Example 1'},
 'id_low': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}})

# DataFrame 2 - containing 1 Example
d2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Example': {0: 'Example 2', 1: 'Example 2', 2: 'Example 2'},
 'id_low': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 6}})

# DataFrame 3 - matching table
dm = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id_low': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 6, 8: 6},
 'id_high': {0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D',
  4: 'E',
  5: 'B',
  6: 'B',
  7: 'E',
  8: 'F'}})
```

d1 and d2 are matchable as you can see above.

**Expected Output (or similar):**

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Example': {0: 'Example 1'}, 'Example_2': {0: 'Example 2'}})
```

**Failed attemps**

Aggregation of with matching table translated values then merging. Considerer using Regex with the OR-Operator.

Comment: Can you please show a pictorial view of the output?

Comment: @Saniya Parveez, Thank you for your question, I have updated my question and attached an pictorial view of the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
d2.merge(dm)
  .merge(d1.merge(dm), on='id_high')\
  .groupby(['Example_x','Example_y'])['id_high'].agg(list)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Example_x  Example_y    id_high
0  Example 2  Example 1  [A, B, E]
```

Comment: Wow, impressive and everything as a 1-liner. d2.merge(dm).merge(d1.merge(dm), on='id_high') was the tricky part for me but seems quite obvious now. Thank you very much!